# How to use grep in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, grep, cut

- I am trying to make a shell script which prints out the last modification dates of the following files.
- Somehow the script just prints out an empty line
- "modified" is a file which contains the names and the modification dates of the files in the following format(delimiter='@'):

```
>modified
for i in file1 file2 file3
do
    echo $i@`stat --printf='%y\n' $i`>>modified
done
```

Having created that file, I'm trying to search it like:

```
for i in file1 file2 file3
do
    var=`grep -w "$i" modified | cut -d'@' -f2`
    echo $var
done
```

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're asking, replacing `grep | cut` with `awk -v word="$i" -F@ '$1 == word { print $2 }'`may be appropriate.

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of the `>modified` at the start of your code and the `>>modified` inside it if you put `>modified` _after the `done` on the same line_. That's more efficient than a whole lot of smaller redirections... though even more efficient than that would be `stat --printf='%n@%y\n' file1 file2 file3 >modified`, avoiding the loop altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Charles, there's no reason to create that `modified` file for that (unless you are planning to use that file for another purpose).

Also, you can give different arguments to your `stat` command, as in:

```
stat --printf='%y\n' file1 file2 file3
```

This gives exactly the same output as what you're aiming for.

Comment: On taking a closer read on the question, I'm assuming that the real source for `modified` (vs the simplified code in the question) is something like source control system history rather than mtimes. That would explain why the OP describes `modified` as a given and is focusing only on their attempts to search it.